# Xamarin.Android how to restrict edit text field to only allow 1 number before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal?

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext, decimalformat

Is there a way to do this?

For example I want the max number before the decimal to be 9.

Example of allowed numbers:

1.56, 
3.68, 
9.9, 
2.1,

I already have a decimal input filter set up to allow a maximum of 2 numbers after the decimal:

```cs
class DecimalFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    //Pattern mPattern;
    String regex = "[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (2 - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    public DecimalFilter(int digitsAfterZero)
    {
        //mPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?");
        regex = "[0-9]+((\\.[0-9]{0," + (digitsAfterZero - 1) + "})?)||(\\.)?";
    }

    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest.ToString(), regex))
        {
            return new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But how can I amend this to restrict the amount of numbers before the decimal and not just after the decimal?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex like below:

```
^\d{0,1}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[image]